# Problems assigning variable to output of command

Tags: bash

I am using `wc -l < songs.txt` to find out how many lines are in `songs.txt`

Then I want to store that as a variable. I've tried these:

```
OUT = $(wc -l < songs.txt)
OUT = "$(wc -l < songs.txt)"
```

I tried a lot from [How to set a variable to the output from a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-variable-equal-to-the-output-from-a-command-in-bash)

But I still get command not found error for OUT

`wc -l < songs.txt` works on its own

What simple thing am I missing here?

Comment: Spaces around the `=` sign are relevant.

Comment: Ok thanks for directing me

Comment: Tip: [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net) automatically identifies this and other problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spaces should be avoided.

```
out=$(wc -l < songs.txt)
```

Comment: The command is correct, but shouldn't it be "*can't have* spaces" instead of "are missing"?

Comment: Yes, you are right.